# What is worst case time complexity for given function?

Tags: time-complexity

```
Void func(int n){
Int k=n;
Int i=0;
for(;i<n;i++){
while(k>1){
k>>=1;
}
}
```

What is worst case time complexity of the function? explain the solution also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop runs `log2(n)` times. This is because `k` is repeatedly divided by 2 (right shift by 1), so its value decreases exponentially.

However for all other iterations of the outer loop, the value of `k` is still less than 1, so the inner loop does not run.

Therefore the time complexity is given by `T(n) = Ө(n - 1) + Ө(log2(n)) = Ө(n)`.